# RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows-7, runas

If I run

```
runas /savecred /user:yogurt\administrator "del c:\testt"
```

I get this error

```
Attempting to start del c:\testt as user "yogurt\administrator" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - del c:\testt
2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

But when I run

```
    runas /savecred /user:yogurt\administrator "cmd"
```

new dos window opens and then `del c:\testt` works just fine.

**Any idea how to fix that on Windows7?**

I want to delete a file that Administrator created. It works only if Administrator deletes it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It thinks you're looking for a file named `del` as the command.  Runas doesn't know that `del` is internal to `cmd`.  Try

```
runas /savecred /user:yogurt\administrator "cmd /c del c:\testt"
```